# Understanding word in the college is 1987

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding, irish-english

The Passage is from Jez Butterworth's Jerusalem. what is this line: "Word in the college is 1987 is going to be worse." means? Also, who is Maureen Pringle?

PROFESSOR: A DJ, eh?

GINGER: That’s right, mate.

PROFESSOR: How does that work?

GINGER: Basically, I spin sick beats. Bring the ruckus. Drop
the bomb on the people at the back ’cause the people at the
back don’t take no slack.

PROFESSOR: Fascinating. It’s Maureen, isn’t it?

GINGER: That’s right, mate. Maureen.

PROFESSOR: Maureen Pringle.

GINGER: Doctor Maureen Pringle. How do you do?

PROFESSOR: How are you finding the funding cuts over
there?

GINGER: I think it’s disgraceful. I don’t see how we’re going
to meet our quotas. It’s like a sausage factory.

PROFESSOR: Word in the college is 1987 is going to be
worse.

JOHNNY: I suggest you bring the ruckus.

GINGER: Just you try and stop me…

PROFESSOR: That’s the spirit, Maureen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unofficially stated [by people] in the college that 1987 is going to be worse.

> Meaning of (the) word is in English
>
> ***(the)*** **word is**
>   used to refer to something that has been reported but not officially stated:
>
> The word is (that) more hostages will be released over the next few weeks.

[(The) word is (Canbridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/the-word-is)

Speaker GINGER tells PROFESSOR that her first name is Maureen and when PROFESSOR says "Maureen Pringle" GINGER adds that she is *Doctor* Maureen Pringle.